# Storyboard or segue from ViewController to Tabbar Controller

Tags: swift, xcode, uiviewcontroller, swift3, uitabbarcontroller

I want to implement a segue / storyboard in a button FROM View Controller TO tab bar controller (Home) in swift 3

[My storyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sym5Q.png)

This is my sign in code

```
@IBAction func LogIn(_ sender: Any) {
    if self.emailTextfield.text == "" || self.passwordTextfield.text == "" {  
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: "Please enter an email and password.", preferredStyle: .alert) 
        let defaultAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .cancel, handler: nil)
        alertController.addAction(defaultAction)
        self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    } else {
        FIRAuth.auth()?.signIn(withEmail: self.emailTextfield.text!, password: self.passwordTextfield.text!) { (user, error) in
            if error == nil {
                print("You have successfully logged in")
                //this is my  storyboard but it gives me black screen
                let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Home")
                self.present(vc!, animated: true, completion: nil) 
            } else {
                let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: error?.localizedDescription, preferredStyle: .alert)
                let defaultAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .cancel, handler: nil)
                alertController.addAction(defaultAction)

                self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
        }
    }

}
```

I tried using storyboard

```
    let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Home")
                self.present(vc!, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

i tried using segue

```
self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "Home", sender: self)
```

both gives me black screen. why? I have a clarification also. where should i connect my segue, is it in the tab bar controller(grey) or to the first TAB controller?

Comment: U need to create tabbar class to navigate from ViewController to TabBarcontroller

Comment: I already did create a HomeViewController.swift. Just to shorten my question: How to segue(if using segue) or storyboard(if using storyboard) FROM a view controller to a TAB bar controller?I know how to segues from view controller to another but in tab bar i didnt know.

Comment: I think you have create new class under UITabBarController for Tabbar, Link - https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1bdnxm63q27cE02dzNod2Yyd3M/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Actually u have to try navigate from ViewController to TabBarController but u did ViewController to ViewController, So that is problem for here

Comment: For you to get an overview of what i have made: http://www.appcoda.com/firebase-login-signup/. I already made this. What i want to do next is after the log in it will directly to a tabbar controller(where it has home tab, profile tab). Q: How to segue from log in to tab bar controller? tried your suggestion it gives me black screen, what's the problem?

Comment: Don't use segue method, Below That I answer for ur question. Please try below method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Below step,

1) Create new function in AppDelegate class

```
func LoginNav()
{
        self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let mainViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("MainTab") as! tabbarControllerViewController // U have to create tabbarControllerViewController for ur TabBarView
        self.window?.rootViewController = mainViewController
        self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

}
```

2) Then call that func from any viewcontroller like below

```
let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
appDelegate.LoginNav()
```

Comment: I am confused where should i put my storyboard id: "MainTab". is in the maintab view controller or the first tab view controller?

Comment: Still, give me black screen. why?

Comment: Select tab bar controller --> Identity Inspector --> Give class name --> change storyboard ID as "MainTab" and then run

Comment: If u still struggle to run, can u able send sample package

Comment: This is the github repo https://github.com/appcoda/FirebaseLoginDemo .. What i want to implement here is instead of a view controller after log in it will direct to a tab bar controller.

Comment: As u wish that I changed above GitHub repo file, Changed Project link - https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1bdnxm63q27UlhCako4VGo3bnM/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Go through above link I have shared solution for ur problem